# .Net 6 : Getting a list of the values ​of a database table based on a list of IDs of that table by Linq?

Tags: linq, .net-6.0

I have a table `Colors` in which the following information is stored:

```
id    name
------------
1     red
2     green
3     blue
4     black
5     white
```

For example, I have a list with ID 1-3-5. How can I get the values ​​of the color table whose ID is 1-3-5?

Comment: Try `Colors.Where(c => idList.Contains(c.id))`. That might translate into the SQL equivalent `FROM Colors c WHERE c.id in (@p1, @p2, @p3)` or similar.